# Between Date Time T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have the following Where clause which is causing me issues and I am looking for a work around.

@startDate is the todays date and @endDate is the end date which could be 7 days, 14 days or 20 days in the future, this works fine unless the end month is greater than the start month.

ISSUE- if the StartDate DAY is 20 and the END Date Day is in the next Month example Start Day is 10/21 and End Day is 11/5 than the where clause cancels its self out, I can't use a Between because we are not including the yr.
I tried an OR but this also doesn't work.

```
 WHERE    DAY(t.AnniversaryDate) >= DAY(@startDate) 
            AND DAY(t.AnniversaryDate) <= DAY(@endDate)
            AND MONTH(t.AnniversaryDate) >= MONTH(@startDate)
            AND MONTH(t.AnniversaryDate) <= MONTH(@endDate)
            AND YEAR(t.AnniversaryDate) < YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: Describe what you want to achieve. For now it looks like **[The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)**

Comment: I want to be able to search between two dates without including the yr.

Comment: Share sample data + desired output.

Comment: THE SQL Works perfectly as long as the future dates have the same month its only when the Month of the End Date Changes

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
select DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'19780517',GETDATE()),'19780517')
```

Will always return the 17th of May of the current year. A similar expression can be used to perform the same trick for any date<sup>1</sup> by replacing both instances of `'19780517'` with the date of interest.

So, whatever "I can't use a Between because we are not including the yr" means, you should be able to work around it by using the above expression.

So, I *think* what you want would be:

```
WHERE    DATEADD(year,
         DATEDIFF(year,t.AnniversaryDate,GETDATE()),
                       t.AnniversaryDate)
         BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate
```

<sup>1</sup>So long as you're happy that 29th February maps to 28th February if you ask for it in a non-leap year.

Comment: This will return a list of dates for example what I would like to do is search Anniversarydate which has a YR and the between StartDate and EndDate which have no YR.

Comment: I can adivice you to change your logic to apply funcitons to the variable side only, never to the column because any index in that column ill be hindered for the sake of this query performance

Comment: @Jean - yes, if you *need* indexes, you have to go for a variant here. You can't avoid the need to calculate on the column (if you think about the nature of the query) but what you do is to create a computed column that normalizes all of the dates into a single year (say, 1978 or 2001) by changing the `GETDATE()` part of the expression, and then index *that* column. Once that's done, you can query it, making use of indexes, but you have to normalize your start and end date values into the same year.

Comment: My bad. Yes you ill need to pull off the variable and useless year part since it ill just make mismatchs.

Comment: I have found that this isn't working on dates 12-20- 1-5 for the new yr?

Comment: This works fine until you get dates like the following 12-25 - 1-05 because 1-05 is in the following yr and we are not including the yr.